# Memory game does not call compare function correctly

Tags: java, arrays, compare, bluej

I have coded a simple memory game. Card values are added to two arrays and after that, a compare function is called. But there is a problem with the logic of the compare function.

The specific problem seems related to the fact that the compare function is called on the third button click. So on first click it adds first value to first array , on second click second value to second array. But I must click for yet a third time to call the compare function to compare the match of two arrays.

The main problem is that after all cards are inverted (10 matches in 5x4 memory game), it does not show the result.

I have uploaded full code here : http://uloz.to/xcsJkYUK/memory-game-rar .

```
public class PEXESO5x4 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JButton[] aHracieTlactika = new JButton[20];
    private ArrayList<Integer> aHodnoty = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private int aPocitadlo = 1;
    private int[] aTlacitkoIden = new int[2];
    private int[] aHodnotaTlac = new int[2];
    private JButton aTlacitkoExit;
    private JButton aTlacitkoReplay;
    private JButton[] aHracieTlacitko = new JButton[20];
    private int aPocetTahov = 0;

    public void vkladanieHodnot() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            for (int j = 1; j < (this.aHracieTlactika.length / 2) + 1; j++) {
                this.aHodnoty.add(j);
            }

        }
        Collections.shuffle(this.aHodnoty);
    }

    public boolean zhoda() {
        if (this.aHodnotaTlac[0] == this.aHodnotaTlac[1]) {
            return true;

        }
        return false;
    } 
    public  void zapisCislaDoSuboru() {
       try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Semestralka.txt", true)))) {
      out.println("haha");
    //more code
    out.println("hahahahha");
    //more code
    }catch (IOException e) {
    //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
     }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     int match = 0;

      if (this.aTlacitkoExit == e.getSource()) {

            System.exit(0);

        }

      if (this.aTlacitkoReplay == e.getSource()) {
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < this.aHracieTlactika.length; i++) {

            if (this.aHracieTlactika[i] == e.getSource()) {
                this.aHracieTlactika[i].setText("" + this.aHodnoty.get(i));
                this.aHracieTlactika[i].setEnabled(false);
                this.aPocitadlo++;

                this.aPocetTahov += 1;

                if (this.aPocitadlo == 3) {

                    if (this.zhoda()) {

                        match+=1;
                        if (match==10)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You win");
                        }

  this.aHracieTlactika[this.aTlacitkoIden[0]].setEnabled(false);
                        this.aHracieTlactika[this.aTlacitkoIden[1]].setEnabled(false);

                    } else {
        this.aHracieTlactika[this.aTlacitkoIden[0]].setEnabled(true);
                        this.aHracieTlactika[this.aTlacitkoIden[0]].setText("");
                        this.aHracieTlactika[this.aTlacitkoIden[1]].setEnabled(true);
                        this.aHracieTlactika[this.aTlacitkoIden[1]].setText("");                     
                    }
                    this.aPocitadlo = 1;    
                }
                 if (this.aPocitadlo == 1) {
                    this.aTlacitkoIden[0] = i;
                    this.aHodnotaTlac[0] = this.aHodnoty.get(i);
                }
                if (this.aPocitadlo == 2) {
                    this.aTlacitkoIden[1] = i;
                    this.aHodnotaTlac[1] = this.aHodnoty.get(i);  
                }          
        }     
    }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the compare function, what is the input and what is the desired result? And what is the actual result? I can see a bunch of code I don't understand. Try not to explain the game, try to explain what's wrong in terms of objects, arrays and collections, integers and so on. The meaning of them is not relevant. The computer that does not behave as you wish does not know about the game either.

Comment: Have you already checked full code example? This is compare function:  public boolean zhoda() {
        if (this.aHodnotaTlac[0] == this.aHodnotaTlac[1]) {
            return true;

        }
        return false;
    }

Comment: Having to download the entire thing is not how this site works. See [ask] and partially [mcve]. What is that function doing, where do those values in the array come from? Put a println in the function and see what values it compares. And put a println in the place that writes to the array and see where it's not doing what you intended to do.

Comment: I edited the grammar and formatting a bit to try to make the problem statement clearer. The code may still need edits by the OP based on the comments.